# The header doesnt take the full width on a android chrome browser

Tags: android, css

My problem with this very basic piece of code is that the `top-header` doesnt take the full width on an android chrome browser.

If I remove the width on the `page-width`, the `top-header` takes full width... But i need to set the width!

How do i make it so the `top-header` takes full width?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<!-- TOP HEADER -->
<div id="top-header">
    <div id="nav" class="page-width">
        test
    </div>
</div>

<!-- CONTAINER -->
<div id="container" class="page-width">
    test
</div>

</body>
</html>


/********** TOP-HEADER **********/
#top-header {background:#719bb5 url(../images/layout/bg_header.png) repeat-x left bottom; border-bottom: 1px #5E7D99 solid; height:59px;}

#container {background-color:red;}

/* classes */
.page-width {width:1000px; margin:0 auto; padding:0 10px;}
```

EDITED:

added image of what it looks like on my android chrome browser

[image]

Comment: Try: html, body, #top-header { width: 100%; margin: 0; padding:0; }

Comment: joholo: that didn't do it...